# Regex Negated Close/Open Tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Found quite a few links related but nothing in the area of how I want it. I want a Regular Expression to match a negated open and close tag. Take this string for example:

```
<p>This <em>is</em> <span>a</span> <b>sentence</b>.</p>
```

I use a regular expression to match `<em>` and `<b>` while leaving `<p>` and `<span>` alone. I do this using the following regular expression:

```
<(?!p|span)[^>]*>
```

Problem is, the above will match `</p>` and `</span>`. I want to leave those end tags out as well. I've tried:

```
<(/)?(?!p|span)[^>]*>
```

and different combinations of it but nothing I've tried works. Hoping I can get some help. How can I set a regular expression to match these *without* doing something like: `<(?!p|span)[^>]*>(.*?)</(?!p|span)[^>]*>` (looks awful and probably takes more resources).

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to remove any html tags that I don't approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
(?:<(em|b)[^<>]*?>)([^<>]+)(?=</\1>)
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?:<(em|b)[^<>]*?>)([^<>]+)(?=</\1>)

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the regular expression below «(?:<(em|b)[^<>]*?>)»
   Match the character “<” literally «<»
   Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(em|b)»
      Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «em»
         Match the characters “em” literally «em»
      Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «b»
         Match the character “b” literally «b»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>” «[^<>]*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   Match the character “>” literally «>»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([^<>]+)»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list “<>” «[^<>]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=</\1>)»
   Match the characters “</” literally «</»
   Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
   Match the character “>” literally «>»
-->
```

---

*This pattern is for match whole tagged data with opening and closing pairs.*

But if you like to remove only the tags, may use:

```
</?(em|b)[^<>]*?>
```

---